# Rails - LoadError (Unable to autoload constant _ expected _ to define it) Only happens intermittently, refreshing fixes the issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Rails 5.0.1 application uses a lot of namespaces, and I've recently been encountering `LoadError (expected to define)` when trying to access controllers. The problem is though, that it only happens sometimes, with different controllers, and reloading the page fixes it.

An example of a controller that caused this error:

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant
API::V1::ProgramRequirements::Requirements::StudentRequirementsController, expected
/app/controllers/api/v1/program_requirements/requirements/student_requirements_controller.rb to define it)
```

An `ls` of the `/app/controllers/api/v1/program_requirements/requirements` directory:

```
{other_controllers} student_requirements_controller.rb
```

The controller:

```
module API::V1::ProgramRequirements::Requirements
  class StudentRequirementsController < ::API::V1::ApplicationController
    # omitted....
  end
end
```

The route:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    namespace :program_requirements do
      resources :requirements, except: [:new, :edit] do
        scope module: :requirements do
          resources :student_requirements, except: [:new, :edit]
        end
      end  
    end
  end
end
```

This problem only recently started happening, and it doesn't always happen with the same controller. I don't have any other controllers with the same name under the same namespace defined.

Comment: development environment ? The problem doesnt appear after a reaload probably because when they are accessed for the first time they are not found and then loaded and thus is available later on.

Comment: @AlokSwain yes, it's in development. Haven't tried it in production yet. I realize this probably won't happen in production because they will be autoloaded when the server starts. I was hoping for a fix so I don't have to deal with it in dev.